# Ruby: using an array of hashes to select values from another array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Say I have two arrays of hashes:

```
array_1 = [{name: "Dale Cooper", role: "author"}, 
           {name: "Lucy Moran", role: "author"}, 
           {name: "Harry Truman", role: "author"}]

array_2 = [{author: "Lucy Moran", title: "Lorem"}, 
           {author: "Bobby Briggs", title: "Ipsum"}, 
           {author: "Harry Truman", title: "Dolor"}]
```

How would I go about selecting from `array_2` just the hashes from authors that are in `array_1`? Preferably, the result would be this:

```
array_3 = [{author: "Lucy Moran", title: "Lorem"}, 
           {author: "Harry Truman", title: "Dolor"}]
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could save all the `array_1` names in a set in order to select hashes from `array_2` :

```
require 'set'

array_1 = [{ name: 'Dale Cooper', role: 'author' },
           { name: 'Lucy Moran', role: 'author' },
           { name: 'Harry Truman', role: 'author' }]

array_2 = [{ author: 'Lucy Moran', title: 'Lorem' },
           { author: 'Bobby Briggs', title: 'Ipsum' },
           { author: 'Harry Truman', title: 'Dolor' }]

authors = Set.new(array_1.map{ |h| h[:name] })

array_3 = array_2.select{ |h| authors.include?(h[:author]) }
# [{:author=>"Lucy Moran", :title=>"Lorem"},
#  {:author=>"Harry Truman", :title=>"Dolor"}]
```